# How to access element through shadow DOM

Tags: primary-key, polymer-2.x

I am trying to select an element that has by id through an imported web component.

Child Element

```
<template>
  <paper-button id="button"></paper-button>
</template>
```

Parent Element

```
<template>
  <custom-element id="el"></custom-element>
</template>

...

select() {
  let address = this.$.el.button.innerHTML;
}
```

However, this returns undefined. Is there a way to sub-query or access the button element some other way from the parent?

Something like `this.$.el(this.$.button.innerHTML);`

or `this.$.el.shadowRoot.button.innerHTML`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the `shadowroot` is selected, you can chain selections together with `getElementById`.

```
this.$.shipMethod.shadowRoot.getElementById('address')
```